# PowerAnimator System Requirements?

Tags: graphics, sgi

I was curious: what was the cheapest/wimpiest computer you could run [PowerAnimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerAnimator) back in the day on?

My guess would be a base model SGI Indy.